# How to upgrade docker container with previous network and volumes?

Tags: docker, docker-network, docker-volume, dockerpy

I'm developing an app where we [pop containers](https://github.com/Coaxis-ASP/opt/blob/master/backend/api/container_services.py) with volumes and custom network.

I need to add the feature where admin will be able to upgrade the running container to latest version. So I was hoping to be able to fetch the various information from it the pop a new container with the old config.

#### Question

However I'm not sure what I really need to grab on the old container and how to use it. For instance,

- Is `NetworkSettings.Networks` enough or is there network information elsewhere in the data ?
- How do I mount a volume with the infos in `Mounts`?

  ```
      {
          "Type": "volume",
          "Name": "841d6a1709b365763c85fb4b7400c87f264d468eb1691a660fe81761da6e374f",
          "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/841d6a1709b365763c85fb4b7400c87f264d468eb1691a660fe81761da6e374f/_data",
          "Destination": "/home/mast/.ssh",
          "Driver": "local",
          "Mode": "",
          "RW": True,
          "Propagation": ""
      }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I still need to check the network part, but using the full path to the previous `Source` as the new source works to mount the volume.

**update**: `volumes` is a list of mount points (destination not the source).

```
import docker
containers = docker_api.containers()

docker_api.create_container(
    image='docker.site.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon:latest', 
    volumes=['/home/mast/.ssh', '/etc/mast'], 
    host_config=docker_api.create_host_config(
        binds={
                "/var/lib/docker/volumes/841d6a1709b365763c85fb4b7400c87f264d468eb1691a660fe81761da6e374f/_data": {
                    'bind': "/home/mast/.ssh",
                    'mode': 'rw'
                },
                "/var/lib/docker/volumes/002730cbb4dd9b37ad808915a60081508885d533fe003b529b8d0ab4fa46e92e/_data": {
                    'bind': "/etc/mast",
                    'mode': 'rw'
                }
            }
    ))
```