# Creating new container with volume from an older doesn't work as expected

Tags: docker, docker-volume, dockerpy

This is related to [How to upgrade docker container with previous network and volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42488732/802365).

#### Original container

```
$ docker inspect zealous_wozniak  --format "{{ json .Mounts }}" | python -m json.tool 
[
    {
        "Destination": "/etc/mast",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    },
    {
        "Destination": "/home/mast/.ssh",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    }
]
```

#### Upgrade container

```
$ docker inspect confident_austin  --format "{{ json .Mounts }}" | python -m json.tool
[
    {
        "Destination": "/etc/mast",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "b053289f632bef2ebddc1a8d1fa8b25c76cb30d2bc990211995faa191b63030b",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/b053289f632bef2ebddc1a8d1fa8b25c76cb30d2bc990211995faa191b63030b/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    },
    {
        "Destination": "/home/mast/.ssh",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "c1438df0435c5c37d202337c7cdf142710d256852b26691fafc90e48818bee15",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/c1438df0435c5c37d202337c7cdf142710d256852b26691fafc90e48818bee15/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    },
    {
        "Destination": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa/_data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "8d0c7c9e89c82f6c9e68a115aef1605362ed08844bc61459e10183c7f56f7c44",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/8d0c7c9e89c82f6c9e68a115aef1605362ed08844bc61459e10183c7f56f7c44/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    },
    {
        "Destination": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16/_data",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Mode": "",
        "Name": "58d7afdf56b64d0a8301366fe5442620571584104297cc1753b97a3d159a0603",
        "Propagation": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/58d7afdf56b64d0a8301366fe5442620571584104297cc1753b97a3d159a0603/_data",
        "Type": "volume"
    }
]
```

#### code

```
def upgrade_daemon_container(container_id):
    old_container_data = docker_api.inspect_container(container_id)
    creation_data = get_upgrade_data(old_container_data)

    new_container = docker_api.create_container(
        image=creation_data.get('image'),
        hostname=creation_data.get('hostname'),
        volumes=creation_data.get('volumes'),
        host_config=docker_api.create_host_config(
            binds=creation_data.get('volume_bindings'),
            port_bindings={80: 80},
            restart_policy={"MaximumRetryCount": 0, "Name": "always"}
        ))

    return new_container
```

Where `creation_data` looks like:

```
{
  'hostname': 'defb4b2697bc',
  'image': 'docker.akema.fr:5000/coaxis/coaxisopt_daemon:latest',
  'networking_config': {
    'EndpointsConfig': {
      'opt_network_aae2d4': {
        'IPAMConfig': {
          'IPv4Address': '10.49.0.2'
        }
      }
    }
  },
  'volumes': [
    '/var/lib/docker/volumes/31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16/_data',
    '/var/lib/docker/volumes/faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa/_data'
  ],
  'volumes_bindings': {
    '/var/lib/docker/volumes/31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16/_data': {
      'bind': '/etc/mast',
      'mode': 'rw'
    },
    '/var/lib/docker/volumes/faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa/_data': {
      'bind': '/home/mast/.ssh',
      'mode': 'rw'
    }
  }
}
```

#### Question

- Why do I have 4 volumes instead of 2?
- Why are the old volumes `Sources` used as `Destination`?

Answer (score 0):

I was mixing sources and destinations in the `volumes` list. Should be

```
'volumes': ['/etc/mast', '/home/mast/.ssh'],
```

instead of:

```
'volumes': [
'/var/lib/docker/volumes/31c0787ccded0a49e1f97e272ac5e37f2a505620b861c13318ff3a49eaef8f16/_data',
'/var/lib/docker/volumes/faaae04539b8ef338a9f6ffecc3098e79d8035d23b07065e8d86fe31bee043fa/_data'
],
```